# Volume button on taskbar doesn't show up any controls

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, audio, icons

Today, when I booted my Windows 10 PC, it was extremely slow, and it takes 15 minutes for everything to be stable. I can use the PC as normal, but how matter I try, I cannot get the volume button in the taskbar to be working. When I clicked it, nothing showed up, no controls show up. I right clicked it, no context menus showed up. Other icons in the taskbar still works normally.

I tried to go into Settings and to the "Sound" part. When I went into the "Sound" part, it froze for minutes before showing the volume settings. I can only control the volume there, and not from the icon on the taskbar. I turned the icon on and off in taskbar settings, but it still isn't working.

Google doesn't tell anything helpful; it only shows me how to fix it when the icon itself doesn't show up. Now, the icon appears, but doesn't do anything. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> my Windows 10 PC, it was extremely slow, and it takes 15 minutes for
> everything to be stable.  I cannot get the volume button in the
> taskbar to be working.

**(A) Try DISM / SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

**(B) If DISM does not solve the issue (it may not), run a Windows 10 Repair Install.**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything and see if that works.
>
> The next options:  Keep Data and Keep Nothing are more aggressive.

A Repair Install will update all the drivers it can and that will be helpful

Comment: I was talking about the volume button

Comment: You also said the PC was running slow. So try DISM and SFC and see if that helps.  DISM will try to repair all settings that it can.